# Insert value of select_box into table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two tables:

```
Topics
-name
```

and

```
Queries
-topic_id
```

A query can have a topic and so I'm trying to create a select_box in my queries_form which inserts a selected topic into my topic_id attribute of my queries table.

What I already made is a functional select_box, but I'm unable to insert the selected item into the topic_id attribute...

```
<% form_for @query do |f| %>
....
<%= f.select :topic_id, :value => 'queries', Topic::find(:all).collect( &:name )  %>
<% f.submit "save" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks a lot for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set your relationships in your model like this :

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :queries
end
```

and

```
class Query < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

Then you can write in your form view this:

```
<% form_for @query do |f| %>
  ....
  <%= f.select :topic_id, Topic.all.collect {|topic| [topic.name, topic.id]}  %>
  <% f.submit "save" %>
<% end %>
```